# How to granulate Chrome's zoom levels?

Tags: google-chrome, default-settings

In Firefox I can do this:

[image]

as you can see whenever I ctrl and +, I zoom with my changed values, 115%, 120%, 125%, etc. in 5% steps. How can I do that in Chrome? I don't want to go from 110% to 125% and WHAM to 150%.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I set a custom zoom in Chrome?](https://superuser.com/questions/463185/how-do-i-set-a-custom-zoom-in-chrome)

Comment: No, because those are extensions and these settings in preference are non-existend. That question and those answers are 8 years old.