# Changing Chrome's default zoom without going to Settings - Appearance

Tags: windows, google-chrome, browser, google-chrome-extensions, zoom

Every day I'm switching default zoom (all pages) between 100% (normal browsing) and 150% (aka Netflix mode or couch mode).

I'm currently doing this from *Settings -> Appearance -> Default zoom*, but is there an extension or a way to make the default zoom switchable via an icon on the main UI without the extra clicks ? Is the default zoom setting changeable from extensions ? If not, can this be achieved using some Windows app that controls scaling for all applications ?

Comment: Kindly check if this similar thread was helpful: [How do I set a custom zoom in Chrome?](https://superuser.com/questions/463185/how-do-i-set-a-custom-zoom-in-chrome)

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is an icon that can be set to change the zoom level. You can use `ctrl` and `+` or `-` to change the zoom from any page.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

There's an [extension available on the Chrome Web Store called 'Zoom'](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/zoom-for-google-chrome/lajondecmobodlejlcjllhojikagldgd) which should help.

This lets you quickly zoom in/out from a button on the Chrome toolbar, as well as adding a right-click menu that you can select a zoom level from.

Answer (score 0):

I created a .BAT script for 100% and 150% zoom levels like in [Is it possible to change display scaling via command line?](http://superuser.com/q/1334781) and created Ctrl-Alt-N keys for them by placing a shortcut to each .BAT file in `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs` .